# Format a number with PHP to always have 2 digits before decimal

Tags: php

I'm trying to format a number in PHP to always have at least 2 places before the decimal and can't seem to figure it out no matter what I google/try. I'd prefer to only do this if there's not a whole number before the decimal.

This would be the ideal desired output, as I do not know the numbers before hand, it changes per page.

```
0.59 becomes 00.59
1.00 stays 1.00
0.43 becomes 00.43
14.56 stays 14.56
```

Any ideas?

Comment: number_format() comes to mind. `1.00` is not "2 digits before decimal" so your format is inconsistant

Comment: why does `1` get exempted from having a leading `0`? is it special, or does that apply to any non-zero leading digit? if it's just 0 that needs padding, then `if (substr($num, 0, 1) === '0') { $num = '0' . $num }` would probably be easiest.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea @Dagon

Comment: @Dagon I figured, but I can't seem to get it to do what I'm trying to do... can't seem to figure out what arguments to feed it to transform 0.59 into 00.59

Comment: 2.1 = 2.10 or 02.10 or ?

Comment: 2.10, basically I'd like to format the number as a price and just make sure if it's under 1.00 that it has 00.59 and not 0.59. Google's JSON rich snippet validator complains if I give it a price that is under $1.00 and doesn't have two leading 0's before the decimal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a 0 if the number is less than 1:

```
$res = (($num < 1) ? '0' : '').number_format($num, 2);
```

Comment: Ended up using this, nice and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do what you want :

```
$num = 0.342;
$num = number_format(round((float) $num, 2),2);
if ($num < 1) $num = str_pad($num,5,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT);
echo $num;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not on Windows, this works:

```
$num = 0.59;
echo trim(money_format("%=0#2.2n", (float)$num));
```

You might also need to add the ! flag if you get the currency symbol in the output.

See [php.net/money_format](http://php.net/money_format)